# Flushing the content earlier in php for increasing page speed

Tags: php, html

I am trying to load header part of doc first at once.and content part after that..For this i m using flushing technique here in following format.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<?php ob_end_flush();?>
<body>
<div id="container">
menu links </div>
<?php flush();?>
<div id="body">
</div>
</body></html>
```

I want to load container div on page load first and then later divs after container.
So i dnt want to load entire page at once,i want to load container first and body divs first...

In php.ini file also i have disabled gzip compression.but still it does not load container div first.
It loads whole page at once which takes a lot of time to load.....Please guide on how to correct the code to load container div first to increase page speed....

Comment: I think you are solving the wrong problem. Find why the overall page load takes more time and try to optimize it?

Comment: no.thats fine.but how can we flush the content in php with flushing technique.I read some articles as well tht its possible

Comment: If you want to do async page loading - you need to use something like ajax and load the other div with javascript + ajax

Comment: no.but i cant implement ajax call here.As we click on a link on first page.we land on this page the code i have highlighted here.I came to know after searching that it can be loaded in parts with flush functions.isnt it possible???

Comment: @john corely i personally never used ob_start(), but reading the docs i think you should use ob_end_flush() instead of just ob_fush(), and after that u can write ob_start() again.

Comment: @johncorely Let's verify whether or not this is a server-side or client-side issue.  Use a packet sniffer to ensure that the data is being sent when you flush your buffer.  If it isn't, the problem is server-side.  If you see the data being sent via packet sniffer but not displayed, there may be some optimization you can do in your markup.  However, not all browsers render partial content equally.  In general for page speed... you disabled your gzip compression which isn't what you should do.  So, you must have a special circumstance where your page takes a **long** amount of server time.

Comment: but if we enable gzip compression.Then flushing process will not work...is it correct????